# Java, "Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT" in OpenCV 3.0

Tags: java, opencv, detection

I found [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B1YsyzmB4wivakxRbjd0SjZBa3c/view) program online which helps in Hand Tracking

I am using OpenCv version 3.0

Since it is written with an OpenCv version older than 3.0, I had to change it.

I did all the conversion but got stuck at this part

```
VideoCapture webcam=new VideoCapture(0);
webcam.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,768 );
webcam.set(Highgui.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1024);
```

What do I do so that this starts working in OpenCv verion 3.0;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use VideoIo now

```
VideoCapture webcam=new VideoCapture(0);
webcam.set(Videoio.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,768 );
webcam.set(Videoio.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,1024);
```

Documentation is [here](https://docs.opencv.org/java/3.0.0/org/opencv/videoio/Videoio.html#CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)